# Applying a function to every observation in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

I have a large df of coordinates that I'm putting through a function (reverse geocoder),
How can I run through the whole df without iterating (Takes very long)

Example df:

```
    Latitude    Longitude  
0   -25.66026   28.0914    
1   -25.67923   28.10525    
2   -30.68456   19.21694    
3   -30.12345   22.34256    
4   -15.12546   17.12365
```

After running through the function I want (without a for loop...) a df:

```
     City
0    HappyPlace
1    SadPlace
2    AveragePlace
3    CoolPlace
4    BadPlace
```

Note: I dont need to know how to do reverse geocoding, **this is a question about applying a function to a whole df without iteration.**

EDIT:

using df.apply() might not work as my code looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    results = g.reverse_geocode(df['LATITUDE'][i], df['LONGITUDE'][i])
    city.append(results.city)
```

Comment: Use multi-threading on the list of items by defining your list comprehension method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759891/correct-use-of-map-for-mapping-a-function-onto-a-df-python-pandas. The answer given there may help you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slower approach Iterating through the list of geo points and fetching city of the geo point

```
import pandas as pd
import time
d = {'Latitude': [-25.66026,-25.67923,-30.68456,-30.12345,-15.12546,-25.66026,-25.67923,-30.68456,-30.12345,-15.12546], 'Longitude': [28.0914, 28.10525,19.21694,22.34256,17.12365,28.0914, 28.10525,19.21694,22.34256,17.12365]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# example method of g.reverse_geocode() -> geo_reverse
def geo_reverse(lat, long):
    time.sleep(2)
    #assuming that your reverse_geocode will take 2 second
    print(lat, long)
for i in range(len(df)):
    results = geo_reverse(df['Latitude'][i], df['Longitude'][i])
```

Because of `time.sleep(2)`. above program will take at least 20 seconds to process all ten geo point.

**Better approach than above:**

```
import pandas as pd
import time
d = {'Latitude': [-25.66026,-25.67923,-30.68456,-30.12345,-15.12546,-25.66026,-25.67923,-30.68456,-30.12345,-15.12546], 'Longitude': [28.0914, 28.10525,19.21694,22.34256,17.12365,28.0914, 28.10525,19.21694,22.34256,17.12365]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

import threading
def runnable_method(f, args):
    result_info = [threading.Event(), None]
    def runit():
        result_info[1] = f(args)
        result_info[0].set()
    threading.Thread(target=runit).start()
    return result_info

def gather_results(result_infos):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(result_infos)):
        result_infos[i][0].wait()
        results.append(result_infos[i][1])
    return results

def geo_reverse(args):
    time.sleep(2)
    return "City Name of ("+str(args[0])+","+str(args[1])+")"
geo_points = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    tuple_i = (df['Latitude'][i], df['Longitude'][i])
    geo_points.append(tuple_i)

result_info = [runnable_method(geo_reverse, geo_point) for geo_point in geo_points]
cities_result = gather_results(result_info)  
print(cities_result)
```

Notice the method `geo_reverse` has processing time of 2 seconds to fetch the data based on the geo points. In this second example the code will take only **2 seconds** to process as many points as you want.

**Note:** Try both approach assuming that your `geo_reverse` will take approx. 2 seconds to fetch data. First approach will take 20+1 seconds and the processing time will increase with the increasing number of inputs but second approach will have almost constant processing time (i.e. approx 2+1) seconds no matter how many geo points you want to process.

Assume `g.reverse_geocode()` method is `geo_reverse()` on above code. **Run both code (approach) above separately and see the difference on your own.**

**Explanation:**
Take a look on above code and its major part that is creating list of tuples and comprehending that list passing each tuple to a dynamically created threads (Major part):

```
#Converting df of geo points into list of tuples
geo_points = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    tuple_i = (df['Latitude'][i], df['Longitude'][i])
    geo_points.append(tuple_i)
#List comprehension with custom methods and create run-able threads
result_info = [runnable_method(geo_reverse, geo_point) for geo_point in geo_points]
#gather result from each thread.
cities_result = gather_results(result_info)  
print(cities_result)
```